# google-services.json: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Dears i am trying to initialize my connection to google Firebase

```
 try{
            Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
            start = new Firebase("https://mymarket-c2448.firebaseio.com/name");
            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://mymarket-c2448.firebaseio.com")
        .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream("google-services.json"))
        .build();
       FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("name");

        myRef.push().setValue("This is first Test");
        myRef.setValue("This is Test");

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
                if (connected) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    System.out.println("connected");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not_connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    System.out.println("not connected");
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println("Error1"+e.getMessage());
        }
```

but at running i get this error

```
10-22 19:05:09.598: I/System.out(5899): Error1google-services.json: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

i tried to use

this.getassets().open("google-services.json") instead of FileInputStreem but same

Thanks

Comment: Where is this file `google-services.json` in your project?

Comment: it's in main directory

/MyMarket/google-services.json

Comment: Put it inside your app directory.

Comment: in which directory exactly, i tried to put it inside assests but still same

Comment: Show a screenshot of your project structure.

Comment: when i put it inside assets i get faild to read service account !!
this is the code of reading json file "this.getAssets().open("google-services.json")"

Comment: this is screen shot


[![google-services.jpg.png](https://s18.postimg.org/gllmp7hpl/google_services_jpg.png)](https://postimg.org/image/ptdv5worp/)

Comment: Is this an eclipse project? I am not aware where you should put the file on an eclipse project. See this link for android studio, https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#3

Comment: Yes, it's Eclipse project, as you aware there is differences between eclipse and android studio for Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to use google-services.json in that way to use Firebase Database in an Android app.  That file is only used at build time after you follow [these instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) to set up your app.  It is *never* referenced inside the app itself.

I also notice you're creating a FirebaseOptions instance, but you're not doing anything with it.  In fact, you typically never have to create a FirebaseOptions object from within an Android app.  The usual case where you need to use FirebaseOptions with a service account is if you are trying to access Firebase from another server.  You do that using [these instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful reply.
Since i want to write to my database from my applicaton i did all the steps in the link that you shared and i got JSON file from there (Configuration file), 

if i tried to use "FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();"
directly then i'll get this error "FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. 
"
so how i can do that ?

regarding FirebaseOptions iam using it with Firebase.inizlize(options)

Comment: You're not supposed to initialize Firebase - it's not part of the integration steps that I linked to.  An init happens for you by default.  You only call initialize if you need to do something special that the default init doesn't handle.

Comment: how i can make sure that the integration is OK or that my code is in the right place ? please advise.